# Add section Include into properties yaml - Anypoint studio

Tags: yaml, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

I am new to Anypoint Studio and MuleSoft, and I am trying to pick up the projects from the previous developer.

In his note, I will need to add the **section 'Include'** into the properties yaml, but I have tried several different ways and still got error, please correct me.

YAML file:

```
apiId: xxxxxx
  
https:
  host: "0.0.0.0"
  port: "8082"

batch:
  data: 
    host: "localhost"
    port: "8082"
    path: "/api/xxx"
    secure: "false"
    scheduler:
    frequency: "1440"

Request:
    targetSystem:
        authtoken:
          XXXXXXXXX

        api:
          XXXXXXXX
          Query:
              param1: XXXX
              paramValue1: "1234"
              reference:
                  include: xxxxx
                  include: xxxxx
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that? How are you using this YAML file in a Mule application? what have you tried? What was the error?

Comment: I want to know if the section include is in the right place, this is the properties yaml file, and the error is deployment fail

Comment: If you don't share details of how the file and the properties are used in your application, and the errors and details of your attempts, it is very difficult that someone can provide help.

Comment: The YAML file is a configuration file, not 'programming' code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a properties file used in a Mule application. Properties files are custom configurations that hold whatever values are used in [property placeholders](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/configuring-properties) in your application. The values and organization are not mandated by a standard, only the format (YAML in this case). Since it is custom configuration for custom applications no one will know where the values should defined in the file or what values, without knowledge of the application.

As an example, in the application you want to reference  property placeholder for the include `${Request.targetSystem.api.Query.reference.include}`

You probably should avoid repeated keys (ie multiple `include` keys). Try naming them differently (include1, include2,...).